# Aqueduct: IsolateSpawnException: Unable to spawn isolate

Tags: dart, aqueduct

When I try to generate a migration file in Aqueduct

```
aqueduct db generate
```

I get the following error

> IsolateSpawnException: Unable to spawn isolate ...

I'm running Aqueduct 3.2.1.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to the newer version of Aqueduct.

```
pub upgrade
```

Note the newer version of Aqueduct that was downloaded. In my case it was `3.3.0-b1`. Activate that version:

```
pub global activate aqueduct 3.3.0-b1
```